# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I keep getting the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error. I think it has something to do with `ngModel` on my input control.

```html
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput formControlName="estimatedCompletionDate" [mdDatepicker]="estimatedCompletionDate" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="milestone.estimatedCompletionDate">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="estimatedCompletionDate" [value]="milestone.estimatedCompletionDate"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #estimatedCompletionDate></md-datepicker>
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using reactive forms then you do not need the `ngModel` attribute and you should remove it.